# How to forward MPMoviePlayerController to specified time in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am new to iPhone development, I need to play videos which are on some link and I have overlay of three labels(like 'jump to 1:20') on the MPMoviePlayerViewController by tapping on the label the movie controller is forwarded to that labeled time. I have tried two functions namely "setCurrentTime" and "initialPlaybackTime" but none of these didn't give result for me..

some help will be very helpful to me. thank you..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime
```

It's part of the MPMediaPlayback protocol. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackTime